# acts_as_taggable with strong parameters in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on, strong-parameters

How can I use acts_as_taggable_on gem with strong parameters in rails 4?

Have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
end

@post = current_user.tag(@post, :with => :tag_list)

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:text, :user_id, :tag_list)
end
```

How can I add (post_params) to @post?

Comment: I have maintained acts_as_taggable_on for a little while. I don't think I would use it in a Rails 4 app, but build the functionality myself.

Comment: @JoostBaaij Could you recommend an alternative?

Comment: In most cases I think the appropriate solution is to build it yourself. It's not that hard. A 3.0.0.rc1 version of acts_as_taggable_on is being prepared, as someone has taken over development of the gem.

Answer (score 10):

You should specify your permitted params like this:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:text, :user_id, { tag_list: [] })
end
```

This should make them save the tag_list in your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

The `tag_list` is passed as an array when you submit the form. So, you should whitelist `tag_list: []` in your strong params definition.

The working code is this:

```
def post_params
  params.
    require(:post).
    permit(:text, :user_id, tag_list: [])
end
```